# C++ class pointer I.e node*

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, linked-list

In c++ liked list Why we have to write node pointer like node* without specifying int, double etc. and we can also declare new node pointers in main without using any node class declaration.

```
   class Node { 
public: 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

If its any different kind of pointer then what it is called?

Comment: I suspect you don't have a good book. In C++, **the** linked list is a template called `std::list< >`, and you don't need to bother with nodes.

Comment: Note: `node*` and `Node*` are not the same thing. Is the question "Why is `Node` treated like a type"? And regardless, you cannot use `Node` without including it in any other place it is used.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
class Node { 
public: 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

there is only one kind of node, and it has an `int` for data. That is why you don't need to write `Node<int>` or `Node<double>`. But you could change your code

```
template <typename T>
class Node { 
public: 
    T data; 
    Node<T>* next; 
};
```

This is called a template, and instead of only having an `int` for the data you can have any type. But now you have to say what that type is when you declare a variable. E.g.

```
Node<double>* ptr = new Node<double>();
```

Comment: Aside: `Node* next` is also possible in the template case